# Application of the Krein Milman Theorem about ball $l^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that ball $l^1$ is the norm closure of the convex hull of its extreme point

Define the extrem point. A point in $K$ is an extreme point of $K$ if there is no proper open line segment that contains point and lies entirely in $K$.

The Krein Milman Theorem: If $K$ is a nonempty compact convex subset of a locally convex subspace X, then $K=\bar{co}$(ext $K$). where ext($K$): the set of extreme points of K and co($K$): convex hall of K

Then, It suffices to prove that ball $l^1$ is nonempty compact convex set.

But, I don't know how to prove. Can I get some hints?

Comment: You mean the closed ball presumably.

Comment: Unless you are in finite dimensions the closed unit ball is not compact.

Comment: Why don't you first figure out what the extreme points are. Use finite dimensions as a guide. Or, in fact, the definition of $\|\cdot \|_1$.

Comment: Right... Then, this problem cannot apply Krein Milman Theorem... In infinite dimension, Does the proposition hold?

Comment: The statement is true. You need to figure out what the extreme points are first. Not too hard to guess by looking at the planar case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the space $\ell_1$ with the weak star topology. It is a locally convex topological wector space, and by Banach - Alaoglu theorem the unit ball is compact in this space. Hence by Krein - Milman theorem it is a closed convex envelope of its extreme points.

Comment: But, unit ball is compact in weak* topology... Can we apply the Krein-Milman theorem?

Comment: The weak-* topology would be on $(l_1)^*$.

Comment: No $\ell_1 =(c_0)^*$ therefore we can consider on $\ell_1$ a weak star topology.

Comment: I think that unit ball is compact in weak-* topology on $(l^1)^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution (albeit I am partial to sledgehammer approaches):

It is not too hard to show that the extreme points of the closed unit ball are $\pm e_k$.

Since $\overline{B}(0,1)$ is convex and closed it follows that
$\operatorname{\overline{co}} \{ \pm e_k \}_k \subset \overline{B}(0,1)$.

Suppose $x \in \overline{B}(0,1)$, and let $x_n =\sum_{k=1}^n x(k) e_k$. Note
that $x_n \in \operatorname{co} \{ \pm e_1,...,\pm e_n \}$, and
$x_n \to x$ (in norm). Since $\operatorname{\overline{co}}\{ \pm e_k \}_k  $ is closed, it
follows that $x \in \operatorname{\overline{co}} \{ \pm e_k \}_k$.

Comment: Can you explain about $e_k$ in $l^1$?? And, Do you assume that ball $l^1$ in finite dimension?

Comment: $e_k$ is the $k$th unit vector. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Why $x_n$ always express finite linear combination?

Comment: $x_n$ is just the first $n$ components of $x$, and $\sum_{k=1}^n |x(k)| \le 1$. Hence you can write $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n |x(k)| (\operatorname{sgn} x(k)) e_k + (1-\sum_{k=1}^n |x(k)|) {1 \over 2}(e_1+ (-e_1)$. It is not too hard to check that this is a convex combination of $\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n$.